# Insert CSV into table using pandas to_sql() ignore wrong rows

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I save pandas dataframe to my SQL database table using `to_sql()`.
If one of rows is of incorrect format, an error is raised and whole dataframe does not get saved.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|',skipinitialspace=True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='"', escapechar="\\")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
try:
  with engine.connect() as conn:
     df.to_sql(name=tablename, con=conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
except Exception as ex:                
     print(str(ex))
```

I tried to split the dataframe by single rows and load them one by one, but it increase loading time by 10 times

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|',skipinitialspace=True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='"', escapechar="\\")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
l = [df.iloc[[i], :] for i in range(len(df))]

for i in range(0,len(l) ):
     try:
      with engine.begin() as conn:
          l[i].to_sql(name = tablename,con = conn, index = False,if_exists='append')
     except Exception  as ex:
           print(ex)
```

How to catch corrupted rows and load the rest?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check that each column in your dataframe has the format that your SQL table is expecting. If you find any values in that column that aren't in the required format you can either filter or update those rows in Pandas before loading your data into the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your approach to insert rows individually and catch exceptions for each row.

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='"', escapechar="\\")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        row_df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[[i]])
        with engine.begin() as conn:
            row_df.to_sql(name=tablename, con=conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error inserting row {i + 1}: {str(ex)}")
```

I just loop through each row in the DataFrame, attempting to insert it into the SQL table one at a time, and catching any errors that may arise for a specific row. If an error occurs for a row, it is displayed, and the script moves on to the next row.

Comment: That I did in my second code example, but that increase time by 100 times, for 10000 rows it's increased from 2 seconds to 2 minutes